# Internationalisation with Gtk# on Win7 32 Bit

Tags: c#, localization, internationalization, gtk, gtk#

I've an C# Application that uses Gtk# and .NET (no Mono). I try to translate the Gtk.Label in this Application but it didn't work.

The mo-file lies under:

> C:\locale\de\LC_MESSAGES\aboutbox.mo

I can access the file and the strings by:

```
// Does not work and results 'Product'
            Mono.Posix.Catalog.Init("aboutbox", @"c:\locale");
            var proPosix = Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString("Product");
// Works and shows translated string
            Mono.Unix.Catalog.Init("aboutbox", @"c:\locale");
            var proUnix = Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString("Product");
```

As a conclusion I think, that the mo file is correct.
The main Problem is, that in Gtk# this doesn't work as well:

The GtkBuilder is initalized:

```
    _aboutBuilder = new Gtk.Builder();
    _aboutBuilder.TranslationDomain = "aboutbox";
    //_aboutBuilder.AddFromString(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(deviceGladePath));
    var result = _aboutBuilder.AddFromFile(deviceGladePath);
```

The Language is set to 'de' on Thread, UiThread, LANG, LANGUAGE. So didn't expect this to be the problem.

Questions:
1) Why is the Gtk# translation not working?
2) Why is Posix.Catalog not working, but Mono.Catalog?
3) How can i set the locale dir in gtk#? (maybe the problem)

I toyed around for days, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to help you, but I successfully used translations in my project. I'm using Xamarin Studio, but I guess it should work using any other tool.

First I set up a translation project inside my solution. Its name is i18n.

Then I init the catalog with Catalog.Init("i18n", "./locale"). When building my project the locale folder contains my .mo files.

Then whenever I need a translation : Catalog.GetString("foo") (or Catalog.GetPluralString, that I haved used yet).

here is some code :

```
using Mono.Unix;
...

    // At startup
    Catalog.Init("i18n", "./locale");

    ...

    // Some code
    Console.WriteLine(Catalog.GetString("Hello, world!"));
```